# LLDB breakpoint "TF_NewSession" is not triggered when I debug tensorflow using LLDB

Tags: c++, tensorflow, lldb

I'd like to learning the C++ source code of tensorflow using lldb debuging as follow.

In one terminal:

```
>>>import tensorflow as tf
>>>import os
>>>os.getpid()
42677
```

In the other terminal:

```
$lldb -p 42677
Process 42677 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x9f6c6e, 0x00007fff8fe37f4e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
frame #0: 0x00007fff8fe37f4e libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 10
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select:
->  0x7fff8fe37f4e <+10>: jae    0x7fff8fe37f58            ; <+20>
    0x7fff8fe37f50 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff8fe37f53 <+15>: jmp    0x7fff8fe30d94            ; cerror
    0x7fff8fe37f58 <+20>: retq

Executable module set to "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python".
Architecture set to: x86_64h-apple-macosx.
(lldb) breakpoint set --name TF_NewSession
Breakpoint 1: where = _pywrap_tensorflow.so`::TF_NewSession(TF_Graph *, const TF_SessionOptions *, TF_Status *) + 31 at c_api.cc:1701, address = 0x000000010ae44ddf
(lldb) continue
Process 42677 resuming
```

Back to the first terminal:

```
>>>sess = tf.Session()
```

This should trigger lldb breakpoint "TF_NewSession" as expected.However it was never triggered no matter how many times I tried. My TensorFlow version is official 1.0.1. 
Could anyone please help me with the problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple explanation for this: currently (TensorFlow 1.0.1 and earlier) the Python API never calls `TF_NewSession()`. Instead it [calls](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ef56133461079f28b61b5a83a62685051408aadb/tensorflow/python/client/session.py#L562) the function [`TF_NewDeprecatedSession()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ef56133461079f28b61b5a83a62685051408aadb/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L1065) (via a [SWIG wrapper](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ef56133461079f28b61b5a83a62685051408aadb/tensorflow/python/client/tf_session.i)). You should set the breakpoint on `TF_NewDeprecatedSession()` instead.

Why is the word "deprecated" in the name? There is an [ancient Google proverb](https://www.quora.com/Every-service-at-Google-is-either-deprecated-or-not-ready-yet-Google-engineering-proverb-What-does-it-mean?srid=J3Kt)....